# how to enable file-access in server server configuration?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am getting following error while uploading image on server-
`Warning: copy() [function.copy]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in D:\Hosting\6448289\html\upload.php on line 112`

corresponding 122 line is-

```
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
```

Comment: $newname contains a scheme like `ftp://host/path/filename`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to have .htaccess files in your hosting directory, you could try adding either of the following to enable allow_url_fopen:

```
php_flag allow_url_fopen 1
php_flag allow_url_fopen on
```

The latter is more likely to work

Answer (score 0):

Is it your own server or a shared one? Seems your hosting does not allow remote connections and it is done for some good reason. Contact your host about this.

Also [this link](http://www.learnphponline.com/errors/url-file-access-is-disabled-in-the-server-configuration) might be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

see
[allow_url_fopen](http://docs.php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.allow-url-fopen)
and [PHP Manual: How to change configuration settings](http://docs.php.net/configuration.changes)

allow_url_fopen is marked as PHP_INI_SYSTEM in php5, so you can only change its value in the php.ini or in a httpd.conf-related config file but *not* via ini_set().